# store function names in an array and call them one by one using array.forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react-native has which has almost 15 `state`s to store some data. Now I want is store all these values (and fetch all of them) in/from internal storage, I'm using [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv).

```
//functions from context api
const {setUsername, setToken, setProgress} = useAppContext();

const getsettingsconfig = () => {
    const keys = storage.getAllKeys();
    console.log(keys);  // ['setProgress', 'setUsername', 'setToken']
    keys.forEach(key => {
      const data = storage.getString(key);
      // I want to set all the values dynamically here
      key(parsedData); // setProgress(data), setUsername(data) etc. like this
    });
  };
```

useAppContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const GlobalContext = createContext({});

export default function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(GlobalContext);
}
```

However, I keep getting

```
 [TypeError: 'setProgress' is not a function]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are these functions defined?  Are they in an included or referenced js file?

Comment: Where did you define those functions you want to call?

Comment: `keys` is a string-array. So, each `key` is a string. If you need to make function-calls, you need to have the function & not a string (which may be the name of the function, for example `'setProgress'` within quotes is a string - and not a function).

Comment: @Programnik Yes, these are inside a context I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way to execute a function whose name is present in an array. The trick here is mapping the name of the function with the function itself (by using the object `myObj`). Then, one simply accesses the object with the key, and executes the function (which is the corresponding value in `myObj` object).

```js
// declaring, defining 4 functions here
// this may even be from useState - same will work
const setField1 = d => console.log('setField1, data: ', d);
const setField2 = d => console.log('setField2, data: ', d);
const setField3 = d => console.log('setField3, data: ', d);
const setField4 = d => console.log('setField4, data: ', d);

// declaring an array of functions
// this can be populated from local-storage - and it will work
const fnArr = [setField1, setField2, setField3, setField4];

// for-each loop to execute each function in the array
fnArr.forEach((fn, idx) => fn(idx));

// using a string array - which will not execute the functions
console.log("\n\n can't execute strings as functions\n\n");
const strArr = ['setField1', 'setField2', 'setField3', 'setField4'];
strArr.forEach(st => console.log(`'${st}' is a string & not a function... one can't execute it`));

// executing the same functions by using the string keys
console.log('\n\n executing functions by using string-names as keys\n\n');
const myObj = Object.fromEntries(strArr.map((k, idx) => ([ k, fnArr[idx]])));
strArr.forEach((k, idx) => myObj?.[k](idx));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```